# Suppress Confirm Form Resubmission dialogue

Tags: javascript, xpages

I want to open some action dialogue for an user to make some selection. The page itself is in read mode. But yes, dialogue has and input field. I want to suppress Confirm Form Resubmission dialogue when user reloads the page. Here is my xPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    enableModifiedFlag="false" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("dialog1").show();}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xe:dialog id="dialog1">
        <xe:dialogContent id="dialogContent1">
            <xp:inputText id="inputText1" style="width:654.0px"></xp:inputText>
        </xe:dialogContent>
        <xe:dialogButtonBar id="dialogButtonBar1">
            <xp:button value="OK" id="button2">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.closeDialog("#{id:dialog1}");]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
        </xe:dialogButtonBar>
    </xe:dialog>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Is this the full complete XML markup of the XPage or an extract only? Is the XPage associated with a document? How do you open the XPage?

Comment: This is full complete XML... it's not associated with any document.. and it's opened as normal xPage.. ...com/mypage.xsp

Comment: get inspired by post/redirect/get pattern. simply, redirect to "get" URL after the dialog. that page won't prompt to resubmit. beware of back button, that's another story

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit ugly, but you can reload the whole XPage after closing the dialog by adding a server-side javascript - in addition to the client-side JS which closes the dialog. I assume that you will include more code and logic in the dialog so you have to ensure that this will be executed too... The code for the close button could look like this:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
enableModifiedFlag="false" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
<xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("dialog1").show();}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xe:dialog id="dialog1">
    <xe:dialogContent id="dialogContent1">
        <xp:inputText id="inputText1" style="width:654.0px"></xp:inputText>
    </xe:dialogContent>
    <xe:dialogButtonBar id="dialogButtonBar1">
        <xp:button value="OK" id="button2">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.closeDialog("#{id:dialog1}");]]></xp:this.script>
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:context.reloadPage()}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
    </xe:dialogButtonBar>
</xe:dialog>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: it doesn't work.. Once I click OK button and close dialogue and try to reload page it brings "Confirm Form Resubmission" dialogue

Comment: can you see that the page really reloads when you close the dialog?

Comment: for better understanding I posted the full XML markup of my page

Comment: Thank you Michael. .It works.. The only difference in your code I see is submit="true". It still doesn't work if I close the dialogue by window [x] button. But that's not a problem. Thanks